# Hashes being pushed onto mongoose model as '[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I am trying to push some things onto a Mongoose model. The model looks like this.

```
var ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hours: Number,
    items: [{number: Number, minutes: Number, details: {description: String}, type: String}],
    userId: Number
});


//later

ScheduleSchema.methods.createNew = function(hours, tasks, breathers) {
    var schedule = makeSchedule(hours, tasks, breathers);
    console.log(schedule);
    this.items = schedule;
    console.log(this.items);
}
```

I think that is enough code for my issue, but I can give more code if needed. Essentially, I've got a method for creating a schedule and then I want to assign the schedule to the object's 'items' property. I must admit I am still learning about mongoose so it is likely a problem there.

Anyway, I know my makeSchedule function is working, because I see this as the output from the first console message.

```
[{ number: 1,
   minutes: 30,
   details: {description: 'Task A'},
   type: 'task'},
 { number: 2,
   minutes: 45,
   details: {description: 'Task B'},
   type: 'task'},
 etc...
 ]
```

However, when the console output from my second log statement, this.items, prints, I don't see the same structure. Instead, I see

```
["[object Object]", "[object Object]", "[object Object]", etc...]
```

Why am I not able to just assign the schedule variable to this.items? I believe I was even able to do it before, but I made some changes to my schedule code and now I cannot.

That would lead me to believe that the error is in my schedule code, but as you can see, it is creating the list of items just fine, based on the console output. Can anyone see a really obvious, potentially mongoose related mistake that I may have missed as a rookie?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you recently added the `type` field to the embedded objects in `items` which is making Mongoose now think that `items` contains an array of strings instead of an array of objects like you have.

To fix it, use an object to define the type for `type` in your schema like so:

```
var ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hours: Number,
    items: [{
        number: Number, 
        minutes: Number, 
        details: {description: String}, 
        type: {type: String}
    }],
    userId: Number
});
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll give it a shot when I get home from the office today.